# Optimizing Deep Clone in Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, javascript-objects

I recently wrote this function for deep cloning an object in javascript, but with the given time complexity it would be extremely slow, any tips on making it more effecient?

```
function deepClone(obj){
  let clone = {};
  for (let k in obj){
    let v = obj[k];
    if (!array.isArray(v)&&("object"!==typeof v)){
      clone[k]=v;
      continue;
    } else {
      if (typeof v==="object"){
        let RCRSD = deepClone(v);
        clone[k]=RCRSD;
      } else {
        if (array.isArray(v)){
          let arr=[];
          for (let e of v){
            if (typeof e==="object"){
              arr.push(deepClone(e));
            } else {
              arr.push(e)
            };
            clone[k]=arr;
          };
        };
      };
    };
  };
};
```

This method also does not account for other data structures which is another problem

Comment: Are you ignoring the functions inside the object?

Comment: You can change the body to `return window.`[`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone)`(obj);`.

Comment: As @jsejcksn says, `structuredClone` now exists. If you need it on an older platform, it is probably better to use the existing `structuredClone` polyfills linked at MDN than to try implementing it oneself.

Comment: This code will also fail to deep clone fields that contain nested arrays.

Comment: As it stands, it is a better fit for Code Review site

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion and check the value of the key

```js
function deepClone(obj) {
  if (obj === null) {
    return null;
  }
  // create a copy of the object
  let clone = Object.assign({}, obj);
  Object.keys(clone).forEach(
    key =>
    // if the value is another object then do recursion
    (clone[key] =
      typeof obj[key] === 'object' ? deepClone(obj[key]) : obj[key])
  );
  // if the value is an array then just make a new copy of the array
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    clone.length = obj.length;
    return Array.from(clone);
  }
  return clone;
};


const a = {
  foo: 'bar',
  obj: {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  }
};
const b = deepClone(a);
console.log(a !== b);
console.log(a.obj !== b.obj)
```

Comment: Love the approach. For cloning an array it might be easier just to do `return obj.slice()`, which effectively does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't necessarily more *efficient* (your code seems to be about there sans the weird conditionals), but it does address some bugs in your code (incorrectly handling arrays), and *just* a bit cleaner.

```js
function deepClone(obj) {
  if(obj === null) return null
  
  const target = {}
  for(const key in obj) {
    if(typeof obj[key] === "object") {
      if(Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
        target[key] = []
        for(let i = 0; i < obj[key].length; i++) {
          const curr = obj[key][i]
          target[key][i] = typeof curr === "object" ? deepClone(curr) : curr
        }
      } else target[key] = deepClone(obj[key])
    } else
      target[key] = obj[key]
  }
  return Array.isArray(obj) ? Object.values(target) : target
}

console.log(deepClone({
  hello: "world",
  one: {
    plus: {
      one: 1,
      equals: 2
    }
  },
  fiveWithInflation: 6,
  arr: [1, 2, { hello: [3] }, 4]
}))

console.log(deepClone([1, 2, 3]))
```